St.BoxLayout with St.Label not being displayed
I'm writing a GNOME overview search provider extension based on this article and I'm struggling with the implementation of createResultObject. The example returns null so the default search results container is used, just like the apps results - a single row of truncated labels in my case. But I want multiple rows each with a name and a link, more like the results from Settings. My first attempt:
/**
 * Create a result object.
 *
 * This method is called to create an actor to represent a search result.
 *
 * Implementations may return any `Clutter.Actor` to serve as the display
 * result, or `null` for the default implementation.
 *
 * @param {ResultMeta} meta - A result metadata object
 * @returns {Clutter.Actor|null} An actor for the result
 */
createResultObject(meta) {
    // return null; // default
    const box = St.BoxLayout.new({
      vertical: true,
      x_expand: true,
    });

    const label = St.Label.new(meta.name);
    box.add_child(label);
    return box;
  }

I'm not seeing any errors but nothing is displayed. What should the returned actor look like?
